# wordpress custom taxonomy display in post edit screen

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have installed the Custom Post Type UI plugin, and created a new CPT called 'Holidays'.
I then created a custom taxonomy called 'Type'.

Fine so far and both appear where they should in the menu.

What I then want to do, is add a few items in the 'Type' taxonomy (ski, sun, divng, camping etc...). With the normal WP categories, I know you add new ones when editing the post, these will build up, then you can select (or rather deselect) the ones you don't want the post to be associated with.

Q:I don't want the user to be able to add these, but rather offer a list of pre-defined choices, that I would input from the 'manage custom taxonomy' in the plugin menu. However any I add there just don't show up in the edit post page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

The plugin by default treats taxonomy as 'tags'... to get them to behave like 'categories' so you can select from a list, you must set hierarchy to 'true' in the advanced custom taxonomy options (in the plugin).